# Proxies for Jest and Pact

Tags: jestjs, karma-runner, pact

What is the equivalent of karma's proxies config option in Jest? I cannot find similar in [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration).
Previously we had something like this in `karma.conf.js`, which allowed us to use actual provider api endpoints (`/api/myFirstApi`) in pacts:

```
proxies: {
        '/proxy/myFirstApi': 'http://localhost:8181/api/myFirstApi',
        '/proxy/mySecondApi': 'http://localhost:8182/api/mySecondApi'
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it has one; Jest isn't running tests in a browser as Karma does, it uses JSDOM for tests of code that needs a browser environment.

Comment: Ok, thx.And do you happen to know some workaround for this issue? the most obvious but very unpleasant and dirty solution would be to sed the pact files before publishing. I'd like to avoid this if possible

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue *is*. Have you tried using https://github.com/pact-foundation/jest-pact?

Comment: ok, in our webapp's services we're calling /proxy/myFristApi for example, which then redirects the request to specific api endpoint (/api/myFirstApi), so in pact file it has to be the same for consumer (webapp) and provider (apis), but the actual call from service which we're using in test is made to /proxy/myFirstApi and after running pact test we get error 'no interaction found ...', because the interaction is registered at /api/myFirstApi and not proxy/myFirstApi
edit: no, we use pact-js rather than jest-pact, but how it can help with this issue?